FLASHLOAN.https://remix.ethereum.org/
i created a contract using remix.ethereum , all went well ,
i linked it to meta mask wallet ,
created a contract and deposited ETH , when i started the arbitrage  i got a MSG debug error
after around 10 MIN , i stopped it and withdrawal the amount however it shows 0 ,
now i don't know where is my ETH.
can someone please support me , let me know for further details
this is the link of the code i used https://rentry.co/gck8eour/raw
Appreciate your support



can you also give the contract link?

You have deployed a scam contract. Your ethers are gone.
